# How to delete all files in one particular directory

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

In Linux, how can I delete all files in particular directory? For example `/home/xd/karthik` is my path; I want to delete all files in the above directory, if the disk usage exceeds 90%. How can I write a script for that?

Comment: We don't generally write your scripts for you.  Do some research on linux scripting, and commands for disk useage, and removing files.  Then write your script.  If you have problems still, post your script, and let us know the specific issue you're having with it.

Comment: Select a language learn it. Have a go and then post any errors

Comment: `rm -R` will be your friend (read the manual).

Answer (score 0):

`rm /path/to/directory/*`

add `rm -r` to remove the file hierarchy rooted in each file argument.

dont need script just basic shell command